# Refining and Preparing Keywords from a column names

Tags: nlp

For the past few days, I've been working on keyword extraction.

A bit of context: The keywords are meant to be names of tables and columns from a database (not necessarily a direct 1:1 mapping). They should be cleaned up, sometimes broken down into multiple words. The goal is to create a bag of keywords that will be used on a webpage for data management, specifically for the "find similar keywords" function, which is currently performing poorly. Here's my current strategy, and I'm wondering how I can improve it:

1. I retrieve keywords from table and column names using an SQL query. In the query, I've implemented logic that pre-processes these words (splitCamelCase, convert to lowercase, replace characters like _ - / with spaces). This results in around 250,000 keywords that look bad:

For instance, below are some keywords:

> ```
> assembly name
> base record type match code table
> azure ad object id for a group
> auto apply default entitlement on case update
> a sync job state
> ```

As you can see, they are not poorly processed. However, more keywords could be derived from them, for instance:

> ```
> auto apply default entitlement on case update
> ```

=

> ```
> auto apply
> default entitlement
> case update
> update
> ```

and so on...

Another issue is the fact that I would like to somehow filter out irrelevant keywords. Sort them in some way by importance. Many keywords look like this, for example: `"cd m path x"` and it would be helpful to process such items as well, without losing important information.

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pyodbc
import csv
import wordninja
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

# Function Definitions

def expand_abbreviations(text):
    words = text.split()
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        if word in abbreviations:
            new_words.extend(abbreviations[word].split())
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(new_words)

def split_compound_words(text):
    # Dzielimy tekst na pojedyncze słowa
    words = text.split()
    
    # For each word, if it is protected, we leave it as it is, otherwise we split it
    split_words = [wordninja.split(word) if word not in protected_words else [word] for word in words]
    

    split_words = [word for sublist in split_words for word in sublist]
    
    return ' '.join(split_words)


def process_text(keyword):
    keyword = keyword.lower()
    # Expanding Abbreviations
    keyword = expand_abbreviations(keyword)
    # Splitting Compound Words
    keyword = split_compound_words(keyword)
    
    return keyword


def compute_lsa_keywords(keywords):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=list(ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS), ngram_range=(1, 2))
    matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(keywords)
    
    # LSA (for test)
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
    lsa_matrix = svd.fit_transform(matrix)
    
    lsa_scores = dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), lsa_matrix[:, 0]))
    sorted_keywords = sorted(lsa_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return [keyword[0] for keyword in sorted_keywords]


# Loading Environment Variables
load_dotenv('.env')
db_user = os.getenv('USER')
db_password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
db_host = os.getenv('HOST')
db_name = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

# Creating Connection String
connection_string = f"DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER={db_host};DATABASE={db_name};UID={db_user};PWD={db_password}"

# Connecting to the Database
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Retrieving Keywords from the Database
cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM data.dbo.keywords_test')
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Abbreviation Definitions
abbreviations = {
    "dwh": "data warehouse",
    "attr": "attribute",
    "cust": "customer",
     ....
}

# List of words to be protected from splitting
protected_words = ["ID", "id", "emails", "users", "date", "update", "updates","workspace", "workflow", "invoice", "dataset", "AI"...]

# Preprocessing Keywords
processed_keywords_list = [process_text(row[0]) for row in rows]

# Computing TF-IDF for Keywords
important_keywords = compute_lsa_keywords(processed_keywords_list)

# Sorting
sorted_processed_keywords = sorted(processed_keywords_list, key=lambda x: important_keywords.index(x) if x in important_keywords else float('inf'))

# Preparing CSV File
with open('processed_keywords_test_rake.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(["processed_keyword"]) 

    for keyword in sorted_processed_keywords:
        csv_writer.writerow([keyword])

# Closing the Database Connection
conn.close()
```

Comment: You're preprocessing routine, however constructed needs to be looked at. If it's not too much code you could post it and we can help you adjust it. There are clear issues that should be easy to fix, but an alternative solution would be someone else helping you rebuild an entire routine from scratch. Its better we work with what you have to get it in a better state.

Comment: I edited my question